# Fragment found in backstack after FragmentTransaction.remove()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have 2 fragments and 1 activity.

I am calling to remove the 2nd fragment from the 1st fragment via the activity like this:

Fragment 1:

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
if(manager.findFragmentByTag("AdFragment") != null){
      manager.beginTransaction().remove(manager.findFragmentByTag("AdFragment")).commit();
      Log.d("BACK", "Removed AdFragment");
}
```

Now when I do back press my onBackPressed method in the activity still finds the just removed 2nd fragment:

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    AdFragment adFrag = (AdFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("AdFragment");
    if(adFrag != null){
        Log.d("BACK", "Found AdFragment from backstack");
    }
}
```

The AdFragment is found even when I remove the fragment in Fragment 1. What am I misunderstanding?
Thanks!

Here is the moment is start the 2nd fragment from the activity:

```
 public void openAdFragment(View v){
    final AdFragment adFragment = new AdFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.adFragmentContainer, adFragment, "AdFragment").addToBackStack("AdFragment").commit();
}
```

Here is the code for starting the first fragment:

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, buildingFragment, "BUILDINGPAGE");
```

Comment: you need to add fragment to stack in transaction , please share more code showing us how you call fragment transaction

Comment: Thanks, I added the code used to start the 2nd fragment. As you can see I am adding it to stack in a transaction.

Comment: where is the code to start the first fragment ?

Comment: Please check the edit. Thanks